# How to apply a dynamic CSS background image and a static background image (multiple backgrounds) simultaneously?

Tags: css

The first background image of my element is fetched from `WordPress`, the second one is static. Here's my current code:

```
<h4 style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('icon'); ?>), url(images/arrow.svg);">content</h4>
```

The `url(images/arrow.svg)` is pretty ugly though because we should specify CSS elements in CSS files only. Is there a way to remove this part from my template file somehow?

Comment: What are you trying to do that isn't just deleting the second image?  Are you removing just because it's ugly?

Comment: Yes just for that reason. Otherwise it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is layer the two images, that way positioning them will be much easier.

The relative positioning on the parent provides a bounding box for the absolute positioned arrow. Then you can just use top, left, right and bottom and position the arrow wherever you want within that bounding box.

```css
.relative {
  height: 184px;
  width: 544px;
  position: relative;
}
.static {
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  top: 62px;
  left: 52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <img class="static" src="http://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  <img class="arrow" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Sideways_Arrow_Icon.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is too different from what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Clearly I misunderstood your question then... Mind clarifying?

Comment: I need to apply 2 background images, one dymanic and one static. The dynamic must be specified in the PHP template file since it's fetched from CMS. But the static one "should" normally be specified in the CSS not in a template file. I'm asking if there's a way to specify this static image in the CSS somehow.

Comment: Couldn't you have two images stacked one on top of another similar to what I've done and just hide the static one after the dynamic one loads using img's onload callback?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I was able to come with is: put the static one on a div (or any container) and make it absolute to position it wherever you want.

and put the other one dynamically as a regular single background.
Ex:

`html`

```
<div>
  <img src='./example.png' alt="example" />
</div>
```

`css`

```
div{
  position: relative;
  background: url('another-background.png');
  img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
  }
}
```